# Using 2D arrays, my arrays don't appear

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

My programm compiles, and it is ok. When I start it and type "AB", they appear on one line, but when I type "BAAB", the "AB" goes under the "BA". I am stuck here for a long time. I will be very glas if you give a solution for this problem.

//it needs to read input from the keyboard and appear every letter     constructed by astersks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char line[100] = { 'A', 'B' };
int i;
int row;
int col;

bool A[7][6] = { {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},    //letter A
                {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
                {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0} };

bool B[7][6] = { {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},    //letter B
                {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
                {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
                {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
                {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0} };

int main () {

    //reads the input
    printf ("Type a word or number, or both: ");
    scanf ("%s", line);

    // loop for every row of every letter
    for (row = 0; row < 7; row++) 
    {
        // loop for every inputed letter
        for (i = 0; line[i]; i++) 
        {
            // if letter is A do this...
            if (line[i] == 'A')
            {
                // lopp for every column to read the asterisks
                for (col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
                    if (A[row][col])
                        printf ("*");
                    else
                        printf (" ");
                }
                printf ("\n");
            }

            if (line[i] == 'B') {
                for (col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
                    if (B[row][col])
                        printf ("*");
                    else
                        printf (" ");

                }
            }

        }

    }
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Trex, what you first need to understand is "What does my code do if I take NO input?". So comment out your initial `printf` and `scanf` and check:

```
//reads the input
// printf ("Type a word or number, or both: ");
// scanf ("%s", line);
```

Output:

```
$ ./bin/multi_array_mess
  *
***  *   *
*  * *   *
*  * *****
**** *   *
*   **   *
*   **   *
****
```

What values of `line` produce that output? `{'A', 'B'}` What happens if `line` contains anything other than `AB`? Try just `'A'`:

```
$ Type a word or number, or both: A
  *
*   *
*   *
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
```

Then with `'B'`:

```
$ ./bin/multi_array_mess
Type a word or number, or both: B
***  *  * *  * **** *   **   *****
```

It should be obvious that a `newline` is missing somewhere in the loop that prints `B`. Changing your logic to match the way you print `'A'` similar to:

```
if (line[i] == 'B') {
    for (col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
        if (B[row][col])
            printf ("*");
        else
            printf (" ");

    }
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Provides the desired output if you enter just `'B'` in response to your prompt:

```
$ ./bin/multi_array_mess
Type a word or number, or both: B
***
*  *
*  *
****
*   *
*   *
****
```

What is printed if you enter anything other than `'A'` or `'B'`? NOTHING. What happens if you enter both `'A'` and `'B'`? (you get a mess).

So it looks just from tinkering with your program, it was designed to print either `A` of `B` using `'*'` as the character depending on the values of `0` or `1` in your arrays. You can either fix the logic to handle `line` containing both `'A'` and `'B'`, or you can limit your input to one character at a time.

Since your intent appears to be able to handle multiple characters in `line` at a time, what happens if we just tweak the loop logic a bit. E.g.:

```
// loop for every inputed letter
for (i = 0; line[i]; i++) 
{
    // loop for every row of every letter
    for (row = 0; row < 7; row++) 
    {
        // if letter is A do this...
        if (line[i] == 'A')
        {
```

Give it a try...

Next, think about how you are prompting for input:

```
printf ("Type a word or number, or both: ");
```

Wouldn't it make more sense to limit your request to what your code will provide output for?

```
printf ("Please enter A or B, or both: ");
```

After receiving input, wouldn't it more sense to check what your user provided before blindly passing the input to the rest of your program? Something simple will do:

```
for (i = 0; i < (int)strlen (line); i++)
    if (line[i] != 'A' || line[i] != 'B') {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input '%c'.\n", line[i]);
        return 1;
    }
```

Now try your program again.

**Printing Each Letter on One Row**

OK. Now that I know what you are intending, it makes it a bit easier to help. In order to print each array as `'*'` or `' '` on the same row, you basically have to loop through each row, checking if a given letter is specified in `line` and print that row for every character you need to print. You can cut down on the code repetition by creating a function to print the row for each array (you can actually use a macro, but we'll leave that for later).

In keeping with the earlier discussion, I added a few sanity checks and created a new character array `allowed` that holds a list of the current characters you have created arrays for (the allowed characters). Just add to it as you add arrays. You will also note I moved all your global variables inside `main`. There is nothing wrong with using globals, but use them sparingly, and only when necessary.

Putting the pieces together, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAXL 100
#define ROWS 7
#define COLS 5

void prn_letter_row (bool a[][COLS+1], size_t row);

int main (void) {

    char line[MAXL] = {0};
    char allowed[] = "AB";
    size_t i, row, len;
    i = row = len = 0;

    bool A[ROWS][COLS+1] = {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},    //letter A
                            {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                            {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
                            {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                            {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                            {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}};

    bool B[ROWS][COLS+1] = {{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},    //letter B
                            {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
                            {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
                            {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
                            {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                            {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                            {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}};

    /* prompt for input */
    while (!*line)
    {
        printf ("\nType a word or number, or both [A-B only]: ");
        if (!fgets (line, MAXL, stdin))
            fprintf (stderr, "error: no input provided - 'ctrl+d'.\n");

        len = strlen (line);    /* get length, remove trailing \n */
        if (line[len-1] == '\n')
            line[--len] = 0;

        char *p = line;
        while (*p) { /* check each character against 'allowed' */
            if (!strchr (allowed, *p)) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid character '%c'.\n", *p);
                *line = 0;
            }
            p++;
        }
    }

    printf ("valid: %s\n\n", line);

    for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

            switch (line[i]) {
                case 'A' : prn_letter_row (A, row);
                    break;
                case 'B' : prn_letter_row (B, row);
                    break;
            }

        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}

/* print given row for letter */
void prn_letter_row (bool a[][COLS+1], size_t row)
{
    size_t i;

    putchar (' ');  /* provide a space before each letter */

    for (i = 0; i < COLS; i++)
        if (a[row][i])
            putchar ('*');
        else
            putchar (' ');
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/chars_from_arrays

Type a word or number, or both [A-B only]: A
valid: A

   *
 *   *
 *   *
 *****
 *   *
 *   *
 *   *

$ ./bin/chars_from_arrays

Type a word or number, or both [A-B only]: B
valid: B

 ***
 *  *
 *  *
 ****
 *   *
 *   *
 ****

$ ./bin/chars_from_arrays

Type a word or number, or both [A-B only]: AB
valid: AB

   *   ***
 *   * *  *
 *   * *  *
 ***** ****
 *   * *   *
 *   * *   *
 *   * ****
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But there comes a problem, my input text needs to appear in one line. I tried to do it only with A and B, but I need to do it with the whole alphabet with uppercase and lowercase letters and also every number and sign. So I need only to appear in one line, not one under another. That's my problem, I can't manage to do it with letters that are repeated.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a look after dinner. You will need to preserve spacing in all of your letters so you don't have to top of 'A' back over the top of 'B', etc..

Comment: Thank you again Mr. Rankin, great help!

Comment: Sure, glad I could help (I hadn't had to think like a dot-matrix printer in a while...). Hopefully, you have picked up a couple of tips on how to approach solving programming problems that will help you going forward. Since you are new to Stack Overflow, one thing you need to do is choose an answer that you found most helpful in answering your question. It can be any one on the page. You do that by clicking on the check-mark next to the number at the top-left  of each question. This is important because it marks the question solved so it can be taken out of the unanswered list. Good luck.

Comment: Mr. Rankin can I have some contacts of you, do you have facebook?

Comment: Yes, but I haven't checked it in about a year. (I don't tweet, not a bird, and I don't facebook -- too old) e-mail is the best, and drop a comment somewhere so I know to look for it. drankinatty at gmail dot com

Answer (score 0):

Here is your fixed code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


char line[100] = {'A','B'};

int i;

int row;

int col;

// Support only latin aphabet, easly expandable
bool chars[26][7][6] = {

                   {  {0,0,1,0,0,0 },   //letter A        
                      {1,0,0,0,1,0 },
                      {1,0,0,0,1,0 },
                      {1,1,1,1,1,0 },
                      {1,0,0,0,1,0 },
                      {1,0,0,0,1,0 },
                      {1,0,0,0,1,0 }},

                   {  {1,1,1,0,0,0 },   //letter B   
                      {1,0,0,1,0,0 },
                      {1,0,0,1,0,0 },
                      {1,1,1,1,0,0 },
                      {1,0,0,0,1,0 },
                      {1,0,0,0,1,0 },
                      {1,1,1,1,0,0 }},
                    // to Z
};


  int main()
  {
       printf ("Type a word or number, or both: ");

       scanf ("%s",line);
       //reads the input
       for (row = 0;row<7;row++)
       // loop for every row of every letter
       { 
            for (i = 0; line[i]; i++)      //loop for every inputed letter
            {

                for (col = 0;col < 6;col++)  // lopp for every column to read the asterisks
                {
                    if (chars[toupper(line[i]) - 'A'][row][col])
                    {
                        printf("*");
                    }
                    else 
                        printf(" ");
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        return (0);
}
```

You can add multiple character support by forming 3d array like

```
bool chars[26][7][6] = {

                   {  {0,0,1,0,0,0 },   //letter A        
                      {1,0,0,0,1,0 },
                      {1,0,0,0,1,0 },
                      {1,1,1,1,1,0 },
                      {1,0,0,0,1,0 },
                      {1,0,0,0,1,0 },
                      {1,0,0,0,1,0 }},

                   {  {1,1,1,0,0,0 },   //letter B   
                      {1,0,0,1,0,0 },
                      {1,0,0,1,0,0 },
                      {1,1,1,1,0,0 },
                      {1,0,0,0,1,0 },
                      {1,0,0,0,1,0 },
                      {1,1,1,1,0,0 }},
                    // to Z
};
```

Than access to array member

```
chars[toupper(line[i]) - 'A'][row][col];
```

in this case you may not use any character `if` checks only `for` loops

this will only works with small string sizes, because standard console support up to 80 characters in length, to deal with it you can setup console width, or perform some manipulation with console cursors to break out formed string properly (like SetConsoleCursorPosition) in Windows.

if you want to support all printable chars, your 3d array should start at whitespace char up to 128 character. For more info look to ASCII character table.

Comment: Thank you very much! But there comes a problem, my input text needs to appear in one line. I tried to do it only with A and B, but I need to do it with the whole alphabet with uppercase and lowercase letters and also every number and sign. So I need only to appear in one line, not one under another. That's my problem, I can't manage to do it with letters that are repeated.

Comment: You should at least use `isalpha()` to determine whether the character value is an actual letter before using `toupper()` and subtracting `'A'`, because if you have a `@` character for example, `toupper()` will return `64` (for ASCII) and subtracting 65 from 64 gives -1, which will invoke undefined behaviour. Also, you should *always* check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: Very useful, everything works, thank you for the help and support!

Comment: Do not forget to flag your question as answered.